# Other ways of saying "versatile platform"?

Tags: science

In my research, I make use of a tool which provides a platform for researchers to investigate phenomenon X in a variety of ways. I want to frame it this way in a paper that I am writing: "Using the --- platform provided by the tool for investigating X, we develop and illustrate a novel method to assess aspect Y of X". I am looking for an adjective to fill ---. "Versatile" comes to my mind. But I feel like there might be better adjectives to use. I don't mind restructuring the sentence if that makes it sound more professional. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest 'flexible'. 'Versatile' suggests to me that tool has multiple possible functions (like a Digital Versatile Disk) whereas you imply that the tool has a limited number of functions but that it can be used to carry out those functions in many different ways.

Comment: Using the versatility provided by the tool; Using the flexibility provided by the tool.

Answer (score 1):

***[Multifunction](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Multifunction)*** suggests the idea of versatility in a technical context:

> - having or able to perform many functions

Dictionary.com

- ....the multifunction platform.

*[multifuction platform](https://www.google.it/search?q=multifunction%20platform&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&biw=768&bih=909&prmd=sinv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD6P_azdHQAhVCmBoKHZsmD2sQ_AUIDCgG)* usage examples in Google Books

> - ....com offers a generalpurpose multitool ***or multifunction platform for any customer***, but it also packages solutions for particular ...

From: Social Networwing for Business